# Fetching Data From Rest Web Service

Tags: apex, webservices

I am new to salesforce and I followed instructions as per salesforce trailhead,

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_webservices

Access token got generated but, when I hit the url error occurs as,

"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Bearer.

But data is fetched successfully when I  try getting data through workbench.

Comment: The best resource for Trailhead challenge issues is the [Trailhead Challenges group](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?feedtype=RECENT&criteria=BESTANSWERS#!/feedtype=RECENT&dc=Trailhead_Challenges&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS)

Comment: The issue is actually not  in solving the trailhead challenge. I tried to expose a restful web service, when I try to get data through workbench, its working but when I try to get data through postman, session invalid error occurs

Comment: Workbench works because you are authenticating with your username and password, so you'll need to authenticate in Postman using either a connected app or some other method.